# C++ Is it a memory leak? Pointer to array alocated dynamicaly in another function

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Quick question. Will this leak and why/ why not?

```
int main()
{
    int array[] = {1,2,3};
    doStuff(array);
    return 0;
}
```

when `doStuff` will do something like this

```
void doStuff(int * arr)
{
    // ...
    arr = new int [50];
    // ...
}
```

EDIT for @Scott Hunter
I think it won't leak because `array` points to memory on stack and I've never heard of memory leaking from stack, but on the other hand i kinda lose any link to this memory.

EDIT2
My problem was I was thinking that changing `arr` in `doStuff` address will change `array` in `main` as well but it won't.

Comment: What do *you* think, and why?  Someone can explain the error(s) in your answer, if there are any.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? This sounds more like an XY problem at the moment.

Comment: _@Square_ Your edit just points out your misconception more. It **will leak**, as I've explained in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it will leak, since you don't call `delete [] arr;` anywhere inside of `doStuff()`.

Note that you don't even change the `int array[];` declared outside of the function.
All you are doing is to change a copy of that pointer that was passed as *by value* parameter.

---

As an aside recommenation:

Don't use raw pointers and raw arrays in c++. Rather use a `std::vector<int>` for your case, and forget about dynamic memory management at all.

Comment: I can't call delelte [] arr since it is not dynamicaly allocated and when i try to i got 'program trigered a breakpoint'.

Comment: @Square Sure you can't do that outside of the function, and I clearly explained why.

Comment: 'arr' in 'doStuff' and 'array' in 'main' points on the same addess and when i do something like 'arr[0] = 100' it changes 'array[0]' too. And the memory that leaks wasn't alocated dynamicaly so it is on stack. I've never heard about leaking memory on stack. Is it so bad that is like you-know-who of memory leaks:D?

Comment: @Square _"... when i do something like 'arr[0] = 100' it changes 'array[0]' too."_ That's not true regarding assignment!

Comment: @Square They only point to the same address untill you change the address that the **copy** of `arr` inside the function points to by assigning it a new address using `new...`.

Comment: What do you mean you aren't dynamically allocating memory? What do you think `arr = new int[50]` is doing?

Comment: Using raw arrays is more efficient and compilers in debug mode can often detect array overflows, which is why I think people should not use wrapper classes for arrays.

Comment: @AppWriter: I've _never_ seen a C++ compiler diagnose an array overflow. Not even once. Are you thinking of "checked iterators" in VS's standard library implementation?

Comment: @AppWriter No, that's just a myth!

Comment: @BoundaryImposition : Visual Studio detects array overflows.

Comment: @AppWriter `std::array` is just as fast as a "regular" array. `std::vector` may be slightly slower due to dynamic allocation and possible caching but it's negligible and vector has a different use case anyway.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I was responding to AppWriter's comment. I just meant that vector has a slightly different use case to array, not that it was a different use case to what OP is looking for.

Comment: @Kevin I wrote it in confusing way. I was thinking about deleting memory that array form main points on not the memory that is allocated in doStuff. I thought that i will lose memory on stack.

Comment: @Square You can't _"loose memory on stack"_ . That's all alreadyhandled by scoping (`{}` blocks).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Now i understand how it works. Big thanks!My bad was i though when i change address of arr the address of array in main will change too.

Comment: @Square Finally you can't change the address of `array` in main, that simple. Please take my aside recommendation if you ever want to write production ready code.

Comment: @AppWriter: So, "yes", then.

Answer (score 5):

`doStuff` takes **a copy** of the `array` pointer. Setting `arr` to something else inside the body of `doStuff` will not modify the original `array` value in `main`.

Therefore, unlesss you call `delete[] arr` inside `doStuff`, your code **will** leak.

Comment: I used std::sort in doStuff and it changed the original array in main, and i can't use delete because i didn't use new[]

Comment: @Square -- Your code includes the line `arr = new int [50];`. That's a dynamic allocation. If you don't delete **that memory** you have a memory leak.